# How to use JQuery Datatable with JSP properly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsp, datatables

I want to use Datatable-Plugin of JQuery with JSP. How does the main approach look like?

I want to load the Datatable with AJAX. But my question is how to do it in general with JSP. Normally I'm using JSF with Primefaces but this is much simpler as to do it with JSP (I don't need any Javascript code to use JQuery-Datables  [example for non-believers](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf)).

Comment: Ok, but maybe you know some good links :-) if you dont know the answer.

Comment: Do you want to load data in table using ajax, or the data is pre-loaded?

Comment: Did you take a look at the site for Datatables?  (http://datatables.net/)  Have you made any attempt at using it?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @David I want to understand how I can use datatable with JSP. (or some other similar framework)

Comment: My first comment is for downvoter )

Comment: @JohnN: Right, but what makes that different from using Datatables with any other server-side technology?  Datatables doesn't interact with any server-side code, it's entirely client-side.  So which server-side technology used is immaterial.

Comment: @David Ok, but where comes the data from ? (I suppose from server) With JSF I only need to fill the special data-List because JQuery-Datatable is integrated in framework. But how can I fill the data with JSP ? So any help is welcome.

Comment: @JohnN: There are some examples under the "Data Sources" heading here: http://datatables.net/examples/  The most common ones I've used are the DOM (for just styling an already-existing HTML table), a JavaScript array (which can be rendered from server-side code) for small amounts of data that should always be on the page, and AJAX (which just makes a request to a server-side resource) for large amounts of data that should be dynamically fetched.  For example, take a look at the `"aaData"` array here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to do two specific things:

1. Create your jsp handler to take a.offset b.pagelength, and make it render json. Lets say you are at this point now (whre you have a variable JSON_DATA)
2. Use code similar to [this pipelined ajax example](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html) to make jquery datatables work with your pagination style.

Also, IMO this is a valid question. So UPVOTE.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Cool ideas :-) More detailed answer were simpler, but your answer give me the notion.

Comment: I use Spring so what is in `server_processing` at controller file ?? explain Ref:https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html